# Select specific character positions from string

Tags: ruby, string, random

I'm looking for a way to select pseudo random characters from a string.

For example, I have a 64 character string. I would like to pick positions 0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9.

Or a harder one would be with the same string, I would pick positions 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12 and so on.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Is the number of characters to be chosen also random? In what sense is the second one harder than the first?

Comment: Where do the positions come from?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you could use [`Array#values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-values_at)

```
> "64charstring".chars.values_at(*[0, 1, 4])
=> ["6", "4", "a"]
```

Update:

And if you'd like to get string result - join the result.

```
> "64charstring".chars.values_at(*[0, 1, 4]).join
=> "64a"
```

Comment: This is nearly perfect!

Comment: @jspartanx86, yes you can join the final array.

Comment: @sawa, that's brutal. When there are positions explicitly asked for in question then there is no need for an answerer to do the random number generation.

Comment: The OP is not explicitly asking for certain positions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that may work well for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Returns a string whose length is a random number between 0 
# and the string length, and whose values are characters from
# random positions in the input string.

def random_string_char_subset(string)
  chars = string.chars.shuffle
  char_count = Random.rand(string.length + 1)
  subset = ''
  char_count.times { subset << chars.pop }
  subset
end


puts random_string_char_subset 'hello'      # => lhl
puts random_string_char_subset '0123456789' # => 821097634
puts random_string_char_subset 'bye'        # => b
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using `[]`

```
a = 'test string'
a[1] #=>e, assuming you are using a known value
a[Random.rand(a.length)] #assuming you want a random value
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer until after I made the edit. Sorry

Comment: Edited so that vee's answer is no longer included in mine, and also so that result is actually random